# Upload an excel file to backend in the form of binary data(using readAsArrayBuffer) in Javascript/Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, binary, filereader

I have to upload and read an excel file from UI and send the file data in binary form to a backend API.

I am using the File reader and reading the file as binary, like below, and passing the fileReader.result to my Node js controller for calling the API.

fileReader.readAsBinaryString(this.file);

At the backend this is throwing some error.
When I am using fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.file) ; I am not able to pass to the controller, since this is object, not a string.

How do I resolve this issue, I want to pass the data obtained from readAsArrayBuffer to the API.

Comment: you do not need to read the file as binaryString just upload/send the file as is

Comment: okay, but I am not able to send this.file in the API, I have to send it as string or buffer; how to do that?

Comment: I need more code to be able to help you, but basically it's going to end up with: `fetch(url, { body: new File(...) })` in the end

Answer (score 1):

Using Angular 2+, one way you can send the file to your server is using the **FormData** with **HTTPClient (@angular/common/http)**. I'm presuming you are using TypeScript and when your clicking uploading you are calling a function called **upload**. So this is a simple example and you can take it as a reference and adapt to your case. The file will be sent as binary:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export class MyFormService {

 constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

 upload(data: IDataModel): Promise<IMyServerResponse> {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const url = 'https://example.com/api/';

      const formData = new FormData();
     
     //If you have just an attachment consider this ---------------------------
     //As suggestion, encode or replace special characters from fileName.
     //The function this.parseFileName is basically doing it.
     const name = this.parseFileName(data.attachment.name);
     formData.append('attachment', data.attachment.file, name);
     //-----------------------------------------------------------------------


      //Or if you have multiple files, consider this one ---------------------
      //Pay attention to the [] after attachment;
      for (const item of data.attachmentList) {
        
        const name = this.parseFileName(item.name);
        formData.append('attachment[]', item.file, name);
      }
     //-----------------------------------------------------------------------

      //Here you post your form data with progress reporting -----------------
      await this._http.post(url, formData, { reportProgress: true, observe: 'events', responseType: 'json' })
        .subscribe(async event => {
            if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
               //Here you can check the progress based on event.loaded 
               //divided by event.total and show to your user.
               
               //Code omitted 
               ...
               ...
            }

            if (event.type === HttpEventType.Sent) {
              //Here your data has been sent to the server.
              //So, based on your server, you can manipulate the request based on 
              //the form field.
            }

            if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
              const serverResponse = event.body as IMyServerResponse;

              //Code omitted
              ...
              ...
              ...

              resolve(serverResponse);
            }
          },
          error => {
            let errorMessage;

            //Code omitted
            ...
            ...
            ...

            reject(error);
          });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the backend code to recieve the file?